# Reading font size from resource file with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a requirement defined by the project's design team for different font sizes for phone and tablet.
I thought, I could store the values using Android's resource resolution and read them with dimensionResource. To my surprise Compose's TextUnit needs the raw sp value, so I am left with reconverting the resolved value back to sp

```
val fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) {
    dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.font_size_h1).toSp()
}
```

which seems like an unnecessary round trip. Alternatively, I could store the values as integer resources and then build TextUnit with:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalUnitApi::class)
TextUnit(integerResource(id = R.integer.font_size_h1).toFloat(), TextUnitType.Sp)
```

which requires use of an experimental Api.

Is there some other solution, that I am missing?

Comment: You are not missing anything - the way of working with text sizes has changed a lot with Compose, and they have chosen not to implement this feature intentionally. The ideal way would be to use the MDC Theme Adapter, but I have updated the linked question with more detail on 3 other options.